# Как добавить данные пришедшие в JSON в инпуты?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, json

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы пришедшие из обработчика в JSON формате данные поместились в инпуты. Например, в строке JSON придет имя пользователя и его фамилия.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data ) {$('#name1').val(data.name);}
        });
    });

пробую делать вот так, но не получается, ругается на что-то;
обработчик возвращает такую строку: {"id":"1","user":"\u0414\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0439","email":"test@test.ru"}

Comment: @ДМитрий, не на что-то, а на отсутствие name

Comment: так...попробовал так "success: function( data ) {$('#name1').val(data.id);", вывалилось "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @ДМитрий, это потому что вы jQuery не подключили или подключили в неконфликтном режиме. `var $ = jQuery;` в начале скрипта поставить и впредь читать сам текст ошибки.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про основы JavaScript и HTML.  
Советую вам почитать учебник **[javascript.ru][1]** прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы...  

С вашей ошибкой поможет разобраться консоль браузера (удобнее всего в Chrome или Opera). Смотрите что вам пришло в ответ на запрос к серверу. Ставьте точки останова и смотрите на значения *data*. Сервер должен возвращать вам именно JSON, а не строку с ним.


  [1]: http://javascript.ru

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо всем кто помог, всё получилось, я счастлив)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может "руками"? Типа так:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  $('#input1').smtJQueryFunction(data.prop1);
  $('#input2').smtJQueryFunction(data.prop2);
  $('#input3').smtJQueryFunction(data.prop3);
  $('#input4').smtJQueryFunction(data.prop4);
});
```

Comment: только `.val();`, а не `smtJQueryFunction()`.

Comment: а что такое "data.prop1"? prop это имя элемента из JSON строки?

Comment: @ДМитрий, да. Только в этот момент он уже должен быть простым объектом, а не строкой.

Comment: Вот я это никак и не могу сообразить, можно прям на примере объяснить?
Вот допустим вернулась строка {"id":"1","name":"Ivan","email":"test@test.ru"}, есть два инпута <input type"text" id="name"><input type"text" id="email">. Как вытащить из строки значения name и email?

Comment: @ДМитрий изучение основ js вам очень поможет.

Comment: наглядный кусок кода поможет куда больше

Comment: @ДМитрий, `$.getJSON()`/`$.ajax({dataType:'json',.. })` вернут вам данные уже в виде объекта (**если** запрошенная страница вернула валидный json).

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про основы JavaScript и HTML.  
Советую вам почитать учебник [javascript.ru][1] прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы...


  [1]: http://javascript.ru